# Solution of PDE on Lipschitz domain which is in $\{ u \in H^1_0 : \Delta u \in L^2\}$ but not in $H^2$

Tags: examples-counterexamples, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I am looking for an explicit example that can be verified that demonstrates this: there is a Lipschitz domain $\Omega$ such that given $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, the PDE
$$-\Delta u = f \text{ on $\Omega$}$$
$$u = 0 \text { on $\partial\Omega$}$$
has a solution $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ with $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ but $u \not\in H^2(\Omega)$.

Preferably the example doesn't use polar coordinates. Does anyone have a reference? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to avoid polar coordinates? The typical examples involve polar coordinates.